# Start a process, and if one of its threads is hogging CPU, suspend it

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c++, process, skype

There's a [well-known problem](https://www.google.com/search?q=skype%20CPU%20hog) that Skype on Windows 8 takes up 100% of one CPU core on some users' PCs. Including mine!  There's a [workaround courtesy of techfreak in Skype Community](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Older-skype-desktop-versions-crash-on-Windows-8-1-but-new-Skype/td-p/2071959):

> 1. Download and run the latest version of process explorer.  (http://download.sysinternals.com/files/ProcessExplorer.zip)
> 2. With Skype running search for Skype.exe in the list of active programs and double click on it.
> 3. Go to the threads tab and Suspend or Kill the Skype thread that is consuming the highest resources when IDLE. (like 50%+ CPU)

I'm getting annoyed with manually doing this after every reboot, so I'd like to automate the steps above, to write a simple C++ or C# "Skype launcher" program that does the following:

- launch SKYPE.EXE
- wake up every 1 second and look to see if one particular Skype thread is taking up over 98% of the CPU cycles in the process
- if found, suspend that thread and exit the launcher process
- otherwise loop up to 10 times until the bad thread is found.

After a quick Google search I got intimidated by the Win32 thread-enumeration APIs, and this "find and kill/suspend evil thread" problem seems to be fairly generic, so I'm wondering if there's an existing sample out there that I could re-purpose.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much more googling and some dead ends with powershell (too many security hassles, too confusing for a newbie) and WMI (harder than needed), I finally found a great [C# sample on MSDN Forums that will enumerate and suspend threads](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d51efcf0-7653-403e-95b6-bf5fb97bf16c/suspend-thread-of-a-process). This was easy to adapt to first check CPU time of each thread before suspending the culprit.

Here's code. Just compile and drop into your startup menu and Skype will no longer heat your office!

```
// code adapted from 
// http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d51efcf0-7653-403e-95b6-bf5fb97bf16c/suspend-thread-of-a-process

using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace SkypeLauncher
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("skype");
            if (procs.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Skype not loaded. Launching. ");
                Process.Start(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(@"%PROGRAMFILES(X86)%\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe"));
                Thread.Sleep(8000); // wait to allow skype to start up & get into steady state
            }

            // wait to allow skype to start up & get into steady state, where "steady state" means
            // a lot of threads created
            Process proc = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
            {
                procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("skype");
                if (procs != null)
                {
                    proc = procs[0];
                    if (proc.Threads.Count > 10)
                        break;
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000); // wait to allow skype to start up & get into steady state
            }

            // try multiple times; if not hanging after a while, give up. It must not be hanging!
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)    
            {
                // must reload process to get updated thread time info
                procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("skype");
                if (procs.Length == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Skype not loaded. Exiting. ");
                    return;
                }
                proc = procs[0];

                // avoid case where exception thrown if thread is no longer around when looking at its CPU time, or
                // any other reason why we can't read the time
                var safeTotalProcessorTime = new Func<ProcessThread, double> (t => 
                    {
                        try { return t.TotalProcessorTime.TotalMilliseconds; }
                        catch (InvalidOperationException) { return 0; }
                    }
                );

                var threads = (from t in proc.Threads.OfType<ProcessThread>()
                                  orderby safeTotalProcessorTime(t) descending
                                  select new  
                                  {
                                      t.Id, 
                                      t.ThreadState, 
                                      TotalProcessorTime = safeTotalProcessorTime(t),  
                                  } 
                              ).ToList();
                var totalCpuMsecs = threads.Sum(t => t.TotalProcessorTime);
                var topThread = threads[0];
                var nextThread = threads[1];
                var topThreadCpuMsecs = topThread.TotalProcessorTime;
                var topThreadRatio = topThreadCpuMsecs / nextThread.TotalProcessorTime;

                // suspend skype thread that's taken a lot of CPU time and 
                // and it has lots more CPU than any other thread. 
                // in other words, it's been ill-behaved for a long time!
                // it's possible that this may sometimes suspend the wrong thread, 
                // but I haven't seen it break yet. 
                if (topThreadCpuMsecs > 10000 && topThreadRatio > 5)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} bad thread. {0:N0} msecs CPU, {1:N1}x CPU than next top thread.",
                        topThread.ThreadState == System.Diagnostics.ThreadState.Wait ? "Already suspended" : "Suspending",
                        topThreadCpuMsecs, 
                        topThreadRatio);
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);

                    IntPtr handle = IntPtr.Zero;
                    try
                    {
                        //Get the thread handle & suspend the thread
                        handle = OpenThread(2, false, topThread.Id);
                        var success = SuspendThread(handle);
                        if (success == -1)
                        {
                            Win32Exception ex = new Win32Exception(Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Exiting");
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                        return;
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (handle != IntPtr.Zero)
                            CloseHandle(handle);
                    };
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Top thread: {0:N0} msecs CPU, {1:N1}x CPU than next top thread. Waiting.",
                    topThreadCpuMsecs,
                    topThreadRatio);

                Thread.Sleep(2000); // wait between tries
            }
            Console.WriteLine("No skype thread is ill-behaved enough. Giving up.");
        }
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int SuspendThread(IntPtr hThread);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern
        IntPtr OpenThread(int dwDesiredAccess, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]bool bInheritHandle, int dwThreadId);
    }
}
```